Help identifying this type of mint
Hello: I had planted some mint seeds I had ordered online, and I’ve realized the seller doesn’t document what mint species and I’m a horticulture newb. Also my dog loves those mint leaves and thinks supermarket mint leaves are trash.
Any help with identifying would be lovely. The leaves are super small I think




How do it smell? With flowers we may be able to find more, but .. if you are looking for scientific name, forget anything you read on labels (so not having a good label is not a problem): too often they just find the scientific name e.g. of mint with obviously error (in this case I have difficulties, but sometime we see such googling back: bad information is way worse than no information). -- also information about the continent/region may help (and the country of the seller)

https://a.co/d/075y3MPD Is the seller listing. Looking more closely, the labeling claims it’s mentha spicata, but the relatively small leaves I have so far don’t quite look that way. And lower on the stems have a purplish tinge. Though this could all be because it’s still a small plant

Swiss flora shows M.spicata with a purple stem. Leaves seems small in the picture (of the flora), but the description say 2 to 7cm long, so I would say not so small. And in any case we have cultivars, so with variations. (and the species has also many related small species, so...). Like tomatoes: taste it, and if you do not like it (maybe because of you, or maybe because of your climate/soil), just change variety (or species).

@GiacomoCatenazzi .. what website do you mean by swiss flora? I tried searching and couldn't find one that has flora search AND information :)

also thank you everyone!

This site: https://www.infoflora.ch/fr/flore/mentha-spicata.html which has the same text as Flora Helvetica (note: you can select French or German language).

To my understanding mint does not come true from seeds, [thus, I'd rate your seller honest for not claiming specific variety for seeds] so if you want more of the mint your dog likes you'll be cloning it.
Rooting hormone helps, but is not essential with mint, normally - they'll frequently manage to root just fine by  putting cuttings in damp substrate, (sand/peat/vermiculite/perlite or a mixture of any or all of those) or even a jar of water (not the ideal rooting method by any means but wildly popular for no good reason...) Or you can simply split the root ball into sections, each with stems, and repot them. Or wait for the plant to start sending out runners.
Mint hybridizes readily so it may not fit any recognized species, exactly.

its definitely fully sprouted with lots of roots,  i'm mostly trying to figure out which of thee standard varieties is closest to. So what are those tiny seed like things i planted if they arent seeds?

I didn't say they are not seeds. They are. The seeds from (some specific mint) may yeild something other than (same specific mint) which is what "not come true from seeds" means.

Gotcha. Thx for clarifying
